# Q my Q was VTC as a dup is misworded, has an accepted A that doesn't A my Q & needs editing

Tags: discussion

I asked the name of [Kirk's fighting style](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/57044/according-to-canon-what-is-the-primary-style-of-hand-to-hand-combat-utilized-by) and my question was closed as already being [asked with two answers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34323/is-the-clasped-hand-strike-seen-in-star-trek-a-real-fictional-martial-art). Neither answer to the other question is accurate due to the wording of that question... A Double Axe Handle Strike is not a [fighting style nor is it a specific martial art](http://www.fightauthority.com/martial-arts-styles.php) . It is a specific move. The answer I have currently accepted for my question is, while not backed up by canon, a fighting style.

I contend that the poster of the [first question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34323/is-the-clasped-hand-strike-seen-in-star-trek-a-real-fictional-martial-art) confused *martial arts* with an individual fighting maneuver and accepted an answer that identified the maneuver, but did not provide the answer to my *What is Kirk's fighting style* question. I feel an edit to the other question would validate my question, but since it has an accepted answer of +20, I wanted to run it through META before I touched it.

Comment: I VtC'ed the second 'answer' on the supposed duplicate: not an answer.

Comment: I've revised my opinion and removed my VTC. The second question is (IMHO) now sufficiently different since it asks about the wider trek universe.

Comment: As the poster of the other question, I'd like to clarify I was just asking about whether the individual move was part of a real or fictional (if any) school of martial arts. I was not clear in my language when asking the question, but the answer did address what I intended to ask. I will edit it to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

They may actually be duplicates, since the older question asks if the specific move is part of a real **or fictional** fighting style.

It is my understanding that questions that cover the same ground, but where one is a more specific version of the other, the *more specific* version of the question should be marked as a duplicate of the more generalized version.

The theory behind this is that good answers to a general version of the question should also answer the more specific version, but that answers to the more specific version may not sufficiently answer the more general question.

I think the [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/57044/according-to-canon-what-is-the-primary-style-of-hand-to-hand-combat-utilized-by) Major Stackings asked about Kirk's fighting style is a perfect example of a more general question that isn't answered by the [more specific version](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/34323/1359).

Answers that describe the general fighting style, how it is referred to in canon (if at all), and any real-world origins, should provide sufficient explanation as to answer "where does that one specific move come from".

However, as the existing answers on the older question show, questions on the fighting *style* aren't necessarily going to be answered by a question focusing on one specific move.

As such, I have voted to reopen the more general question, and, should it be re-opened, I propose that the older question be marked as a duplicate of it.

Comment: The current answer on the question discussed here does not address the answer to the other question. It mentions Kirk's fighting style in general, but it does not name the martial art he uses at all. It does not cover the move specifically asked about in the other question.

Comment: Whether one specific answer addresses the other question actually is not at all relevant for whether the *questions* are duplicate. The answer on the newer question, btw, absolutely does name the martial arts used by Kirk and other members of Starfleet (Judo, an assortment of made-up moves, Aikido, Anbo-Jyujitsu, etc.). Your question was "is this move part of a real/fictional martial art?". The answer on Major Stackings question discusses the larger issue of what real/fictional styles are used in general.

Comment: If yours isn't a duplicate because the other doesn't explicitly name the "double axe handle strike", then by the same logic we can then have dozens of variations of "what is the name of the move where Kirk/Spock/etc. doex *x* while fighting?".

Comment: Note also that a question being closed as a dupe doesn't mean its *bad*. The dupe question doesn't get deleted, reputation earned isn't lost, etc.. Dupe is to link the questions so relevant information is easily searchable.

Comment: How would I go about asking about that particular move then? It's used frequently across multiple TV series in the Trek universe. If the answer to his question is, "Karate", am I to just assume the double-axe handle strike has no name and is just "a karate move"? That would be wrong. I cannot infer the answer to my question from any answer to his question that does not go out of its way to address this particular move. I feel it's an iconic move. Maybe that opens the door to questions about every punch or hold, but shouldn't we address that with downvotes/VTC as too localized?

Comment: Um... Didn't you *already* get the answer to your question? You seem to be arguing that your question shouldn't be marked a dupe because then you'll never get to find out that the move you asked about is a double Axe handle strike. The answer you already received won't magically disappear if your question is marked as a dupe.

Comment: I'm saying it's not a dupe because the questions don't address the same things. The answers just give a point of reference when talking about them. I didn't think the presence or acceptance of answers made them any more or less duplicates of each other. I don't think the policy on closing a duplicate should have anything to do with whether or not answers already exist, but based on whether or not the questions are asking the same thing. As I've said, the newer question does not address what I had asked.

Comment: As I've said, your question asks two things: what is the name of that movie, and *is it part of a specific martial arts style used within the Star Trek universe*. I wholeheartedly disagree that the two questions don't both address what martial arts styles are used with u n the *Star Trek* universe. You're welcome to disagree, but I'm not clear on your justification for that stance. you should probably post your own answer to this meta, rather than arguing your case in comments.

Comment: To make this perfectly clear, whether two questions are duplicates is **almost entirely** dependent on **their answers**. The only case I can think of where that might not be the case is when they're literally the same question, e.g. two questions that ask (with slightly different wording) "What form does Harry Potter's Patronus take?" Otherwise, a question (A) is a duplicate of another question (B) when an answer on question B satisfactorily answers question A. In this particular case, I'd say that's not currently true.

Comment: Even in the above case I mentioned, at least one of them would have to have been answered before one could be closed as a duplicate of the other, unless they were asked by the same user (which isn't likely to happen on [scifi.se]).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist sorry, but that's simply not true. Answers don't determine whether questions are duplicates.  At all.  *Potential* answers,  maybe, but just because one question hasn't received an answer yet doesn't mean it can't be adequately covered by another question. If I ask "what form would Malfoy's patronus take", don't get an answer, and someone else posts "what are all known patronuses? " they're still clearly dupes.

Comment: @Beofett What you're saying is totally contrary to the network wide policy for every Stack Exchange site. When voting to close as a duplicate of another question, that other question *has to have an upvoted or accepted answer*. You'll also notice that when a question is closed as a duplicate, the text at the top says "This question already has an answer here". Not "This is asking the same thing", or "This might be answered here".

Comment: @AnthonyGrist care to back that claim up with sources?  Because I recall seeing no such rule.

Comment: Here is an [example](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1365/what-determines-how-close-questions-can-be-before-being-determined-duplicate) where a more specific question was closed in favor of a more general one, even though none of the answers on the more general question addressed the more specific one.

Comment: Has policy changed?  Because [this meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133956) states *the exact opposite* of what you claim is the "network wide policy for every Stackexchange network".

Comment: [More meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165933/changes-to-close-as-duplicate). Note that the suggestion for the new changes are highly downvoted, and the highest voted answers both indicate that the idea that questions can't be marked as duplicates unless there are accepted answers is a counter-productive restriction, at least in some cases.

Comment: @Beofett http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux In particular: "That's because **the proof is in the answers**. If the question looks the same, but the answers aren't solving the asker's problem, *that is not a dupe* – that is a legitimate new question."

Comment: There is a difference between "accepted policy across the entire stackexchange network" and "here are some experimental new changes that are being tested whose answers overwhelmingly disagree with the idea that dupes can't exist unless there's an answer." That being said, you appear to be correct in that policy has changed, at least on a temporary,  experimental basis.

Comment: Of course,  in this case, both questions have answers....

Answer (score -1):

I agree, those aren't duplicates. While discussing similar subject matter, you are asking about the fighting style, the martial art, while the supposed duplicate is asking about a specific technique.